# Как дождаться ответа сервера?

Tags: веб-программирование, ios, swift, xcode

Всем привет!

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно дождаться ответа от сервера и заполнения списка пользователей "users", чтобы метод "getFriends()" возвращал заполненный список. Сейчас он этого не дожидается и возвращает пустой список.

Вот мой класс и метод для запроса:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class WebRequest {

    static let url = "https://api.vk.com/method/"
    
    static func getFriends() -> [User] {
        var users = [User]()
        
        let fullURL = url + "friends.get"
        
        let parameters: Parameters = [
            "fields": "id,first_name,last_name,photo_200_orig",
            "v": "5.120",
            "access_token": Session.instance.accessToken!
        ]
        
        AF.request(fullURL, method: .get, parameters: parameters, headers: nil)
            .responseJSON {(response) in
                let json = JSON(response.value!).dictionaryValue["response"]?.dictionaryValue["items"]
                
                users = JSON(json).map { User(json: $0.1)}
        }
                
        return users
    }
}
```

а вот метод класса TableViewController где он вызывается и соответственно ничего не отрисовывает (список же пустой):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
                    
    self.friends = WebRequest.getFriends()        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проще всего сделать метод `getFriends` асинхронным

```
static func getFriends(completion: @escaping ([User]) -> Void){
    let fullURL = url + "friends.get"
    
    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "fields": "id,first_name,last_name,photo_200_orig",
        "v": "5.120",
        "access_token": Session.instance.accessToken!
    ]
    
    AF.request(fullURL, method: .get, parameters: parameters, headers: nil)
        .responseJSON {(response) in
            let json = JSON(response.value!).dictionaryValue["response"]?.dictionaryValue["items"]
            
            let users = JSON(json).map { User(json: $0.1)}
            completion(users)
    }
}
```

Тогда используем его так

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    WebRequest.getFriends {
        self.friends = $0
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Это работает! Спасибо!